# How to print UTF-8 data in latin1 database?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

My issue is I have a database which was imported as UTF-8 that has columns that are default latin1. This is obviously an issue so when I set the charset to UTF-8 on php it gives me `�` instead of the expected `ae` character.

Now, when I originally had my encoding as `windows-1252` it worked perfectly but then when I validate my file it says that `windows-1252` is legacy and shouldn't be used.

Obviously I'm only trying to get rid of the error message but the only problem is I'm not allowed to change anything in the database at all. Is there any way the data can be output as `utf-8` whilst still being stored as `latin1` in the DB?

Comment: go over this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through if you haven't already

Comment: I've just looked at that, the problem is I cant change the .ini as it's a webserver and I do not have access to that file. Also I can't change anything at all in the DB layout or structure.

Comment: there's more in that Q&A than `.ini` files or db structure. check your file's encoding and try a meta tag if you haven't read/tried it.

Comment: I have set a php header charset and the webpage is reading it as UTF-8, the issue is the data is obviously not being output as UTF-8. i'll go have another read thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Time ago, I used this function to resolve printing texts in a hellish page of different lurking out-of-control charsets xD:

```
function to_entities($string)
{
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string, array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')); // and a few encodings more... sigh...
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding, false);          
}

print to_entities('á é í ó ú ñ');
```

Comment: That is masking the real problem.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But can help to show the text without problems, while the real problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

1252 (latin1) can handler `æ`.  It is hex `E6`.  In utf8 it is hex `C3A6`.

`�` usually comes from latin1 encodings, then displaying them as utf8.  So, let's go back to what was stored.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I suspect it will say `CHARACTER SET latin1`, not utf8.

Then, let's see

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

to see the hex.  (See hex notes above.)

Assuming everything is latin1 so far, then the simple (and perhaps expedient) answer is to check the html source.  I suspect it says

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Changing to `charset=ISO-8859-1` may solve the black diamond problem.

But... latin1 only handles Western European characters.  If you need Slavic, Greek, Chinese, etc, then you do need utf8.  I'll provide a different answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do this after looking through the link that Fred provided, thanks!

if anyone needs to know what to do

if you have a database connection file. inside that, underneath the mysqli_connect command add

```
mysqli_set_charset($connectvar, "utf8");
```